# how to dynamically generate page links in october cms

Tags: octobercms

I am trying to create a dynamically generated navmenu based on the pages created in the backend I thought I  could use something like {% for page in pages %} to get a list of created pages I have read the documentation and I see you can use { '' |page } and { '' |app } which give the same value ie http://website/ but would like to get the list of all pages like the walker file in wordpress any idea how would achieve this.

```
==
<?php
use Cms\Classes\Theme;
use Cms\Classes\Page;

function onStart() {
   $currentTheme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
   $allPages = Page::listInTheme($currentTheme, true);
   $this['allPage'] = $allPages;
}
?>
==
<div class="lt-navbar navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="lt-no-background">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="lt-container container">
        <a href="{{ 'home'|page }}" class="brand-logo white-text"><img src="{{ 'assets/img/pages/all/logo.png'|theme }}" width="177" height="55" title="Logo" alt="Logo"></a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-menu" class="lt-mobile-toggle button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul>
            {% for page in pages %}
            <li><a href="{{ page.baseFileName|page}}">{{page.title}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
</div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use Built in System classes for that

```php
use Cms\Classes\Theme;
use Cms\Classes\Page;
```

> Then to get all the pages within the current theme

```php
$currentTheme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
$allPages = Page::listInTheme($currentTheme, true);
```

> In code section

```php
use Cms\Classes\Theme;
use Cms\Classes\Page;

function onStart() {
   $currentTheme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
   $allPages = Page::listInTheme($currentTheme, true);
   $this['allPage'] = $allPages;
}
```

> In template

```
<ul>
{% for page in allPage %}
    <li>< a href="{{ page.baseFileName|page}}">{{page.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thank you Hardik  for your advise I have tried this, I am using the Octaskin theme so I put the code in the layouts file then I also put thecode in partial/pages-all/navigation.htm file but still unable to get any values to parse

Comment: opps there is typo from my side .. `{% for page in pages %}` needs to be -> `{% for page in allPage %}` . sorry for that. we need to use `allPage` variable. I checked and its working fine

Comment: Thank Hardik I thought it might have been because at first I copied and pasted your code but its working a treet now thank you again